# Make condition to hide the render if the page is change on ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have default template on rails using camaleon CMS like this:

```
<header id="header">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="logo text-center">
          <%= link_to 'welcome' do %>
            <%= image_tag('kopihub-logo.jpg', class: 'img-responsive') %>
          <% end %>
          <div class="spasi"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Partial Header -->
      <%= render 'partials/header' %>

    </header>


    <!-- Partial Section -->
    <%= render 'partials/main' %>


    <div class="container">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
```

I want to make condition if the pages is changed from the default (ex=  localhost:3000), then all the partials render will be hidden (not showing up on other pages, ex= localhost:3000/about will not showing all the partials render). It's difficult to create another views file since i'm using CMS and generate the pages automatically and will show up on yield section.
Can anyone help me how to make that condition? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use condition like this for the partial renders:

```
<%= render('partials/header') if request.fullpath=='/' %>
```

This will only render the partial if you're on the root page.

It seems like you can't modify your controllers, but if that's an option for you, you should create a separate layout and use it in the appropriate controllers.

Comment: Ah thx for helping me. it's work.
yeah since i'm using CMS so the modifying is restricted

Comment: I'm really sorry if posted here again. If i want to reverse that condition, how you do that? ex: i want all the partial renders show up except on the root @michalvalasek

Comment: Just replace “if” with “unless”.