# Make condition to the partial render on all pages except root (ROR)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've already did posting related with this on:
[Make condition to hide the render if the page is change on ROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48419871/make-condition-to-hide-the-render-if-the-page-is-change-on-ror)

but now i want to reverse that condition, how you do that? ex: i want all the partial renders shows up on every pages except on root. All the source code is same with the previous post. Thx

Comment: just reverse the condition

Comment: `<%= render('partials/header') unless request.fullpath=='/' %>`

Comment: use `unless` instead of `if`

Comment: ah okay thx for helping me with this simple condition. I didn't know this before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following to nice rails condition

```
<%= render partial: "partials/header" unless request.fullpath=='/' %>
OR
<%= render "partials/header" unless request.fullpath=='/' %>
```

Or nicer and understandable

```
<%= render(:partial => "partials/header") unless request.fullpath=='/' %>
```

Also, this to be understandable

```
<% unless request.fullpath=='/' %>
  <%= render partial: "partials/header" %>
<% end %>
```

To your layout

Hope it helps

Comment: nice for giving me many options to choose.
Thx